# Is it possible to activate a css class that effect the html tag depending on the route?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

I'm creating a react site that *ONLY* in the home page ( " / " ) should have:

```
    html{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

but when I move to any other page ( " /something " ) that css is active
(that css is in the home.css that is linked only in home.js)

All the following code is 
App.js:

```
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/page" component={Page} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      );
    }
```

Home.js:

```
    import './Home.css';
```

Home.css:

```
    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
        html {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    }
```

Pagge.js:

```
    import './Page.css';
```

Page.css:

```
    (nothing)
```

I expect the page "/" to use the css of Home.css and the other page to not use the Home.css

Comment: Can you check `this.props.location.pathname`?

Comment: We can configure Webpack and the CSS Loader to parse CSS and load it in the browser. We can write CSS for a component and be certain that it won't leak into other components. You can also have confidence that adding a new component to your application won't interfere with any other components on the system. Take a look of this article :https://javascriptplayground.com/css-modules-webpack-react/

Comment: take a look of this part `{ test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader' }, { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'css-loader', query: { modules: true, localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' } }` modules: true turns on the CSS modules mode

Comment: CSS modules is just a way to automatically namespace your css so that your module styles don't interfere with one another. It won't help with this question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css imports aren't added and removed dynamically, they're all hoovered up and injected in to the `<head>` or bundled into a single css file when you build your bundle(s).

Adding or removing a style to your `<html>` tag as you navigate is possible but it is going to be messy. It will be far easier (and saner) to re-structure your app so that you can apply the `overflow:hidden` to a containing element on some pages but not others.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be achieved by css but you can use inline style like below:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="Home" style={{overflow: window.innerWidth >= 1024 ? 'hidden' : 'initial'}}>
      <h1>Home </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Page() {
  return (
    <div className="Page" style={{overflow: 'initial'}}>
      <h1>Page</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```